# Master equation solution for idealized atoms in heat bath

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

Consider a system of $N$ idealized atoms, each having two energy levels $E= \pm \varepsilon$, that is brought into contact with a heat bath at temperature $T$. Each atom only interacts with the bath itself giving it the probability (per unit time) $\omega_+(t)$ of transitioning to the upper level if it finds itself in the lower one and vice versa for $\omega_-(t)$.

We are asked to find the relaxation time $\tau$ in terms of $\omega_+(t)$ and $\omega_-(t)$ that characterizes the approach of this system to equilibrium.

The answer is given as follows:

[image]

, although there is something that I don't understand.  How do we get to $n_{eq}$?

Comment: What book is this from, out of curiosity?